# Updates to the site

Tags: discussion, design

You may have noticed some updates to the design lately, they are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework.

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

> **But more importantly, it gives you access [to the new profile](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/current)!**

If you see any bugs please let us know in the form of answers (to this post) that illustrate one particular thing at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I've been looking forward to it!

Comment: _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ … 1, 2, 3 … _‹refresh›_ ****

Comment: … _‹refresh›_  

Comment: Nice work! Looks great.

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This issue has been fixed.

---

Very nicely done. I like a lot of the little refinements (and of course having the new profiles is nice).

The most obvious change to me was the font stack, and the choice of Lusitana looks great! It's much more readable. My only thought is that's also a bit small. The main body is at the lower edge of whats comfortable for me and the comments and sidebar text comes across as if it was trying to be small print. I don't usually like running sites zoomed in (and often I use a reduced size) so it's a little unusual that running at 110% is more comfortable for me. Perhaps the base <sub>font size could <sub>use a nudge?</sub></sub>

Comment: Definitely: comments in particular are tiny.

Comment: Yes in general everything looks very good. The svg vote buttons look amazing (especially with a higher pixel ratio)! The text is all readable for me, but smaller than I'd prefer, and smaller than the other sites.

Comment: I think the small text is making the comment upvote image look especially big too...

Comment: I do like it, but at this font size I generally prefer a sans-serif font. The difference is especially noticeable on the main page, in the question previews.

Comment: Font size has been increased in some places. Could you confirm it's not readable?

Comment: @Paweł There's now almost minimal serifs: just the posts and the comments. Wven the comment signatures are san-serif! The design kind of feels like it can't decide whether to commit to serifs or not...

Comment: @Paweł The size is a little better, but really  not there yet. If it was 80% of a what I would expect in a normal base size before it's feels like it moved to 83%. Also curiousdannii is right, the use of sans-serif for some _body content_ such as question summaries kind of gives the whole thing a fractured feel.

Comment: It appears we still don't have a real italic or bold (at least on Windows). That's not good. I think the comments should go back to sans, as they did on ELU. Georgia didn't work for comments there. Comments **should** look different, because they are eminently deletable.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This issue has been fixed.

---

The spacing on the user profile bits below posts needs some work:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 5):

The spacing for badges looks unbalanced: there should be more space on the left and less on the right.

Original: [image: screenshot] "fixed": [image: screenshot]

Compared to ELL's or a beta site's, which both look very nice:
[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Sci-fi's is pretty unbalanced too FWIW:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Pawel The badges are smaller now, but I think the issue was that there is more black space on the right side of the badge than the left.   I.E. the words aren't "centered."  (Well, that's my issue with it at least.)  It was confusing due to the different badge sizes in the post, and I thought it was about the size at first too, but it would be cool if the spacing could be fixed too.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's fixed either. They are still very unbalanced.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This issue has been fixed.

---

Why do we have a "1" in the title now, immediately following "Christianity"?

[image]

Comment: And the word Christianity is black, whereas before, wasn't it a shade of blue?

Comment: It's not a one. It's the first part of the m for "meta". This is the Meta logo. Someone has mixed up the files.

Comment: See also [the separate meta question for this issue](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5810/30).

Answer (score 4):

There's some kind of odd font sizing issue for the question titles on the main page. Lower case "t" in particular seems to be affected:

[image: "t" in "taint" seems smaller than the other letters]

It looks like the "t" ("taint" and "Satan") is several points smaller than the other letters. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: It looks like the WOFF font file for Lusitana is poorly hinted on some systems. There are a couple sizes where the base sizes look inconsistent and also some letters look like they are improperly kerned. I suspect both boil down to a hinting problem.

Comment: @Caleb I have no idea what you just said :-D (outside of kerning which I sort of understand)

Comment: Similarly an x in a comment looks overly big. exe

Answer (score 2):

There's a thin blue line beneath the header which I don't remember seeing before - looks like the spacing is off by 1px.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No repro here, what are your current browser and OS ?

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Chrome 46, win 10, pixel ratio 1.5

Comment: can you make sure you haven't zoomed the page manually? i can't reproduce this bug :(

Comment: @Paweł It happens at the normal 100% zoom.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now. If it comes back again I'll make a new question for it.