# Why do smart quotes not appear as smart quotes in Christianity.SE, but they do in BH.SE?

Tags: bug, design

Does anyone have an idea why smart quotes do not appear when typed in Christianity.SE, but they do appear when typed in Biblical Hermeneutics (BH).SE?

For example, I am typing beginning and end smart quotes in the post creation/editing box by using Alt+0147 and Alt+0148, as follows: “ ” On the other hand, these are beginning and end dumb (straight) quotes: " "

While the smart quotes do in fact appear as smart quotes in the post creation/editing field, when I actually submit the post and view them, they appear to be dumb (straight) quotes. Yet, if I do this exact thing on BH.SE, they both appear as smart quotes here while I type in the post creation/editing box and also after I submit the post.

What could explain that?

Here is a screenshot of what I type while editing a post, versus what appears when I post:

What I type before posting:

[image: Screenshot of edit box, with smart quotes]

What appears after posting:

[image: Screenshot of result, not showing smart quotes]

Comment: Even though the current default font doesn't have glyphs for proper quotes, don't give up using them! They _do_ show up in the mobile apps, when reading posts through a feed reader, when syndicating the content in other places, and we can hope someday SE uses a font without so many shortcomings (this isn't the only issue with it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary font used to display text on this site is Lusitana.  This is different from the one used on BH.SE (Helvetica Neue) because that site uses the standard Beta design (see [this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5793/21576) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162031/300411); you can also confirm by looking at the actual CSS for [BH.SE](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/hermeneutics/all.css?v=85d2c0010872) and for [C.SE](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/christianitymeta/all.css?v=6c3342d86425)).

Helvetica Neue supports curly quotes, but according to [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lusitana), Lusitana does not:

[image: Lusitana]