# Why do quotation marks look weird?

Tags: bug, design

Curled quotation marks don’t look curled.

- Left double quote: `&ldquo;`: “ (looks identical to an uncurled quotation mark: `&quot;`: ").
- Right double quote: `&rdquo;`: ” (ditto).
- Left single quote: `&lsquo;`: ‘ (looks like a backtick or grave accent: `&#x0060;`: `).
- Right single quote: `&rsquo;`: ’ (looks like an uncurled apostrophe: `&apos;`: ').

Of these, the left single quote is the worst offender. If it too looked like an uncurled apostrophe, we would simply have less than ideal typography. But since it looks like a backtick, it’s horribly ugly and actually hard to read.

This is new. I often use curled quotation marks, and I’ve never noticed this before. Something has changed.

Comment: Related: [Why do smart quotes not appear as smart quotes in Christianity.SE, but they do in BH.SE?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6025/21576)  This doesn't directly explain why the left single quote would be coming out as a backtick, nor if something has changed recently.

Comment: Because the font the designer saddled us with on graduation is terrible.

Comment: They look good to me. Android chrome browser.

Comment: @fredsbend The mobile site template doesn't use the same font.

Comment: @Caleb Is there a way we can get the font changed? There are so many problems with this font, it was the first thing I noticed when I discovered this stack.

Comment: @fredsbend Similarly, I'm on the app now, and it looks fine.

Comment: Related: [Can we have a font with better italics?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/can-we-have-a-font-with-better-italics) The smart-quote thing is mentioned in comments on an answer at that question.